# Javascript, trouble with spaghetti code and organization

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, code-organization

I'm making a 2 player chess game which involves a lot of logic.  It's the first time I've written a program that involves a lot of logic, inheritance, and code organization.  I find myself running into a lot of spaghetti code and functions that don't limit themselves to doing one thing like I know is good practice.  I've tried to think of ideas to limit my spaghetti code but am uncertain of the best way to go about it. Here's an example of something I run into a lot.

```
if (that.selected && that.selected != target) {
  if (that.positions[target] && that.positions[target].color == piece.color) {
      ...
  } else {
    var ind = xyz...;
    if (piece.type == "king" && ind != -1) {
    } else {
    ...
    }
  }
```

My best idea thus far for reducing this is to move the conditionals into separate functions (for example, instead of the first line of my posted code I could do something like...

```
var selected_non_target = selectedNonTarget(that.selected, target);
if (selected_non_target) {
  continue above code;
}
function selectedNonTarget(selected, target){
  if (selected && selected != target) {
    ... maybe do some stuff ... 
    return true;
  }
}
```

But I don't really see how this would help and is much more code...  Here's the repository. I would love any suggestions. https://github.com/natecraft1/javascript_chess/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your own suggestion is a good start.  You can reduce it a little bit -- no need for the first `var`:

```
if (selectedNonTarget(that.selected, target))
{   
    // continue above code; 
} 

function selectedNonTarget(selected, target){
    // return a bool -- resist the urge to do other things here   
    return (selected && selected != target); 
}
```

This is good coding practice to reduce a compound condition to a well-named function and then treat it like a simple true | false in your main logic.  This should help reduce the cognitive load as your code base grows -- and every little bit helps.

Sure we all understand what `&&` and `!=` are supposed to mean and do but at 2am after 12 hours of coding, you'll be less error-prone with `if (selectedNonTarget(that.selected, target))`

I would also strongly recommend spending some time splitting the 1000 or so lines of code you have into multiple files.  You will find this worthwhile.

Comment: So it is worthwhile to make a function even if it's just doing a simple boolean check?

Comment: I would say it is worth it only if it is a compound condition, you can name it well, and maybe also the compound condition is used in more than place.  When the compound condition has three or more conditions the payoff is better.